# How to show first character in a string in invoice?

Tags: invoice

```
<?php 
$ship= "{{var shipping}}";
echo $ship;
?>
```

I have used this code to show

```
"Delivery date"
```

in invoice. And output is

```
"Priority Delivery(withing 2 WD)".
```

Now i want to show first character in this string. such as . Out put is "P".

Comment: you can use `echo $ship[0];`

Comment: its not working. because of $ship ="{{var shipping}}"; so that when i use echo $ship[0]; then output is "{"

Comment: where do you write this code `<?php $ship= "{{var shipping}}"; echo $ship; ?> ` I mean which file ?

Comment: /web/app/design/frontend/.........../template/fooman/pdfcustomiser/shipment/bottom.phtml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using fooman pdf customizer. You can find the order id in top.phtml. By this you can easily get your shipping / delivery info. :)

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getPdfHelper()->getSalesObject()->getIncrementId());
                    $ship = $order->getShippingDescription();
                    $fChar = substr($ship,0,1);
                    $lftString = substr($ship,1);   
                 if(isset($ship)) {
                  echo ''.$fChar.'';
}
```